# cakephp setting a value in controller not working

Tags: button, cakephp, addition

I am doing a small project using cakephp. I did a users list table with a button near each user with the text "Add as Friend". In the database, I have a table called friends, which holds an ID, user_id(the user that clicked add as friend) and friend_id(the person the original user wants as friend). Now, I did the following method inside my UsersController:

```
public function addFriend($id)
{
    $usersFriendsTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Friends');

    $uid = $this->Auth->user('id'); //Id of the currently logged in user

    $userAndFriend = $usersFriendsTable->newEntity();

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $userAndFriend->user_id = $uid; //trying to set the user_id field to the id of the user that logged in
        $userAndFriend->friend_id = $id; //trying to set the friend_id to the parameter id


        $userAndFriend = $usersFriendsTable->patchEntity($userAndFriend, $this->request->getData());

        if($usersFriendsTable->save($userAndFriend))
        {
            $this->Flash->success('User Added as Friend!');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Flash->error("User not Added as Friend!");
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing is that, upon clicking the button, it does not even enter the:

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
```

and i know this because, if I set the values before the post, I get the correct values, however when I set the values after, I get nothing and just get redirected to the home page..

This is the code for my button:

```
echo "<td>".$this->Html->link('Add as Friend', 
[
    'controller' => 'Users', 
    'action' => 'addFriend', 
    $u->id
], 
[
    'class' => 'btn btn-success col-md-12'
])."</td>";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check what request method was used: `debug($this->request->method());`

Comment: Please don't echo html tags!  In entity allow user_id and friend_id   https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment